# Apparent verbosity of Boolean return from Javascript function

Tags: javascript, return, boolean, idioms

A common idiom in much Javascript code I've studied is

```
function () {
    ...
    if (some big expression or something) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Why not just:

```
function () {
    ...
    return some big expression or something;
}
```

I know that some people prefer the former for debugging or something but the pattern seems to be more frequent in Javascript code and I wondered if it was a workaround or idiom for some reason.

Sometimes it might be to force a non-Boolean to Boolean but frequently the expression is definitely already Boolean such as

```
    if (complicatedFunctionCall(para1) > 0) ...
```

so conversion/casting isn't required.

Comment: first one is more readable

Comment: What if `some big expression or something;` returns a `non-boolean`?

Comment: Minifiers are plentiful and do a good job.

Comment: I'm more inclined to use the second option, that is, return the result of the expression directly - converting it to boolean with `!!` if necessary, though usually it already is.

Comment: OK, so it's just down to opinion or æsthetics.  Thanks.